# Allow reverse-order sorting on various lists

Tags: support, sorting

I was trying to see my least voted questions in the Answers section of my home page, but found there is no option to see it on top (in reverse order).

Although I can choose from three buttons in the top right corner of the section (i.e. votes activity and newest), I cannot change the order.

Answer (score 3):

All these lists have paging - you can click through to the last page.

Comment: This answers `How do I find my least voted questions`. But I think the feature request is  `I want see the least voted questions *on top*`

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: click through to the last page *and then turn your monitor upside down*.

Comment: @Matt fonts should be turned upside down as well - like this: *uʍop ǝpısdn ɹoʇıuoɯ ɹnoʎ uɹnʇ*

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter [ʎllɐǝɹ 'pɹɐɥ ʇ,usɐʍ ʇɐɥʇ](http://reface.me/status-updates/rotate-text-flip-text-turn-text-upside-down/ "just follow this link to find a 'magician' who does it for me")

Comment: @gnat nice. it would be ʇorʇurous to do it your self

Comment: @gnat: ‮ Now tilt it sideways

Comment: The [new tag][http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new] page does not have pagination, makes tag cleanup a pain :(

Comment: @Manishearth true , hope to see new implementation soon... :)