# How can I jump to the oldest page of comments for a user?

Tags: discussion, comments

Suppose I want to find the oldest page of comments of a user by URL. Here is mine

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/717650/etemon?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=27

But as you can see, in order to open this page, the URL link should end with "page=27". But I can't use this URL link forever, because I might add many comments. Hence the page 27 wouldn't be the last page and it would end with "page=29" for example to open this page.

Is it possible to go to the oldest page of comments by URL even though the number of pages of comments change?

Comment: @RandomPerson I found using for example page=99999 leads to this page. But there is no comments in it.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to customize the order of that page. The alternative is to [use SE API that can sort comments by creation date ascending (i.e. oldest)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users#page=1&pagesize=10&order=asc&sort=creation&ids=717650&filter=default&site=math&run=true)

Comment: There have been feature requests for sorting the activity page ([Can we order the items (comments, answers) in activity tab as well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144506/can-we-order-the-items-comments-answers-in-activity-tab-as-well), [Allow reverse-order sorting on various lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129772/allow-reverse-order-sorting-on-various-lists)) but they have not been implemented.